# Generate Latitude/Longitude From Input Fields Before Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to take the values entered into the fields `street address`, `city`, `state`, and `zipcode` and then use those values to populate hidden fields for `longitude` and `latitude`.

An example of what I'm sort of trying to do can be seen [here](http://tristandunn.com/projects/jquery-auto-geocoder/), I'm just trying to do it with multiple input fields.

The `{...}` within `value=" "` is for the CMS expressionengine so it can be ignored

form fields:

```
<div class="formsection clearfix">
    <label for="trainer_address">Street Address</label>
    <span class="directions">This will NOT be displayed in your listing. Only for search Purposes.</span>
    <input type="text" name="trainer_address" id="trainer_address" value="{trainer_address}">
</div>

<div class="formsection clearfix">
    <label for="trainer_city">City</label>
    <span class="directions">The city to be displayed in your listing.</span>
    <input type="text" name="trainer_city" id="trainer_city" value="{trainer_city}">
</div>

<div class="formsection clearfix">
    <label for="trainer_state">State</label>
    <span class="directions">The state to be displayed in your listing.</span>
    <select name="trainer_state">
        {options:trainer_state}
            <option value="{option_value}"{selected}>{option_name}</option>
        {/options:trainer_state}
    </select>
</div>

<div class="formsection clearfix">
    <label for="trainer_zip">Zip Code</label>
    <span class="directions">The zip code to be displayed in your listing.</span>
    <input type="text" name="trainer_zip" id="trainer_zip" value="{trainer_zip}">
</div>
```

Here are the hidden latitude and longitude fields:

```
<input type="hidden" id="trainer_longitude" name="trainer_longitude" value="{trainer_longitude}" />
<input type="hidden" id="trainer_latitude" name="trainer_latitude" value="{trainer_latitude}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use google geo coder for this. Just tie the onchange on all your address fields, when you have the full address you can do some thing like this to get the longlat. Btw the address format is pretty forgiving any value accepted by google map it is also acceptable here.

// Reference
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng

// Include 
script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">

```
// the method to get the geocode
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function getLatLng (address, callback){
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, function(results, status){
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            callback(results[0].geometry.location)
        }
        else {
            callback(false);
        }
    });
}

// how to use it
getLatLng ("1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC, United States", function(result){

    if (result == false){ alert("ADDRESS IS NO GOOD"); }
    else {
        alert("Lng: " + result.lng() + " Lat: " +result.lat());
    }    
});
```